# How to access elements of a struct in C?

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct in my code.
Structure of struct is:

```
struct student{
    int Id;
    char Name[30];
    char Subject[30];
};
```

i want to read a text file containing these information and want to add these information in an array of this struct.

Here is the structure/content of my text file:

```
1/usman/phd
2/usman/mphill
1/usman/abc
```

Here is my code to retrive the values from the text file and save it into the array of struct and then print the values:

```
void loadStudentData(){
   FILE *fp;
   char buff[255];
   char line[50];
   struct student studentList[20];
   int itemIndex = 0;
   fp = fopen("student.txt", "r");
   while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)!=NULL) {
        struct student studentObject;
        int i = 0;
        char *p = strtok (line, "/");
        char *array[3];
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            array[i++] = p;
            p = strtok (NULL, "/");
        }
        printf("\n");
            for (i = 0; i <= 2; ++i){
                if(i == 0)
                    studentObject.Id =  atoi (array[i]);
                if(i == 1)
                    strcpy(studentObject.Name ,array[i]);
                if(i == 2)
                    strcpy(studentObject.Subject, array[i]);
                   // printf("%s", array[i]);
            }
            studentList[itemIndex] = studentObject;
            itemIndex = itemIndex+1;
   }
   fclose(fp);

   for(int x=0; x<= sizeof(studentList); x++){
    printf("%s", studentList[x].Name);
   }
}
```

but this code is not working. can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Your code looks fine, except for `x<= sizeof(studentList)`. Better use `x<itemIndex`.

Comment: What is your problem? What do you expect and what do you get? And what is your input?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie thanx... this was the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int x=0; x<= sizeof(studentList); x++){
    printf("%s", studentList[x].Name);
}
```

That won't work as expected, `sizeof` gives the size in bytes of the object. Like [Paul Ogilvie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3100312/paul-ogilvie) said, in your while loop, have a counter. You seem to have one, so use `itemIndex` instead of `sizeof(studentList)`

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but you need `for(int x=0; x < sizeof(studentList) / sizeof(studentList[0]); x++){` in order to iterate the elements of the array

Comment: @KeineLust , he already has a count of students so that wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I didn't see the `itemIndex` part.